# Rails ActiveRecord join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having trouble creating a Rails 4 ActiveRecord with Postgres db query that filters by an array of ids through a has_many through join table.

For example:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :available_options
  has_many :options, through: :available_options
end

class AvailableOptions < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :options
  belongs_to :example
end

Example.joins(:options).where(item: true).where(options: {id: [1,2,3]})
```

This will return all examples that have either 1 or 2 or 3 as options. I would like to return examples that have ALL the options, and only ALL the options.

Is there a way to conduct a query like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following with your models

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :available_options
  has_many :options, through: :available_options
end

class AvailableOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :option
  belongs_to :example
end
```

And your query should look like this

```
Example.joins(:options)
 .where(item: true)
 .where(options: {id: [1,2,3]})
 .having("count(options.id) = 3")
```

---

To make it more dynamic

```
option_ids = [1, 2, 3]
Example.joins(:options)
 .where(item: true)
 .where(options: {id: [1,2,3]})
 .having("count(options.id) = #{options_ids.size}")
```

Comment: Having was used for filter group? Missing group_by statement?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ideally, we will find the AvailableOption(s) which have all id [1, 2, 3]

   `option_ids = [1, 2, 3]`

   `join_sql = AvailableOption.where(option_id: option_ids).group(:example_id).select(:example_id).having("COUNT(*) = ?", option_ids.size).to_sql`

The above sql returns all example_id(s) that we need

2. Joins with Example to get the final result

   `Example.joins("JOIN (#{join_sql}) AS TEMP ON id=TEMP.example_id").where(item: true)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
option_ids = [1, 2, 3]
Example.joins(:options)
 .where(item: true)
 .where(options: {id: option_ids})
 .group(:id)
 .having("count(options.id) = #{options_ids.size}")
```